# Want to send messages using webRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I want to the code in JavaScript with the simple explanation on how can i establish connection between my two browser window using console on the same laptop and send multiple messages. I have seen multiple youtube video but there is not clear explanation how to do it with the proper working of all the function provide by browser APIs.

Comment: You can refer to the following web pages:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation

And try to code it, you can post your problem when you get stuck.